# for each ajax post to another file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So i have a for each function that prints the "local" column from this database:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqfZJ.png

It is working all good till here, this is what i get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BltvE.png

Now i want to send variables by post, when the user clicks on different menu items, i've tried everything, but i cant get it to work. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM credenciais_sensores where ambiente = '1'";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                 foreach ($results as $result){
                       $local = $result['local'];
                        $local = substr($local,0,7);
                   echo "<li><a class='clsPostData' data-oxiid='".$result['oxi_sensorid']."' data-oxikey='".$result['oxi_apikey']."' data-redoxid='".$result['redox_sensorid']."' data-redoxkey='".$result['redox_apikey']."' href='#'>".$local."</a></li>";
                   }
          ?>
```

This is working fine, the menu is being printed as i want, but now i cant get to post the data i want, like the "oxi_sensorid",  etc... Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
    $('.clsPostData').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var objPost = {};
          objPost.oxiid = $(this).data('oxiid');
          objPost.oxikey = $(this).data('oxikey');
          objPost.redoxid = $(this).data('redoxid');
          objPost.redoxkey = $(this).data('redoxkey');
          $.ajax({
             url: 'getObjects.php',
             type: 'post',
             data: objPost
          }).done(function(responseFromPhp){
             //Do something with the response, like
             alert(responseFromPhp.message);
          });
    });
});
      </script>
```

And my getObjects.php file:

```
<?php
   $oxiid = $_POST["oxiid"];
   $oxikey = $_POST["oxikey"];
   $redoxid = $_POST["redoxid"];
   $redoxkey = $_POST["redoxkey"];

   $response["message"] = "Grettings from php, we receive your data: ".$oxiid . $oxikey . $redoxid . $redoxkey;
   echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

But i'm always getting the popup saying "undefined" when i click on any menu item... Any help?

Comment: What is the actual response from the server?

Comment: When i click on any menu item, i get a popup saying: Local host says: undefined. So i guess the values aren't being posted...

Comment: Well, the value you're alerting is: `responseFromPhp.message`.  So that's undefined.  But what is the value of `responseFromPhp`?  Examine the actual response from the server.  Debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem there is you need to set the dataType to json. Try adding `dataType: 'json'` after `type: 'post'` on your ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getObjects.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json', // add this
    data: objPost
}).done(function(responseFromPhp){
    //Do something with the response, like
    alert(responseFromPhp.message);
});
```

Comment: Ayos sir (y). OP please try his answer and give feedbacks.